# Render a table in the rows of another table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, html-table

I want to create something like this in react:

[image]

I create a renderTable and a renderInside function. Inside renderTable I call renderInside like this:

```
const renderInside = (slipsList) => {
  if (slipsList) {
    return (
      <table className="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="table__header">
              <div className="table__header__text">
                <span className="table__header--selected">
                  Symbol
                </span>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {slipsList.map((slip, i) =>
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{slip.amount}</td>
            </tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>Loading...</div>
  );
};
```

and the renderTable is like this:

```
const renderTable = (slipsList) => {
  if (slipsList) {
    return (
      <div className="table-scrollable-container">
        <div className="table-scrollable">
          <table className="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th className="table__header">
                  <div className="table__header__text">
                    <span className="table__header--selected">
                      Date Valeur
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="table__header__arrow" />
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {slipsList.map((slip, i) =>
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td className="table-sticky--first-col">
                    {slip.confirmationDate}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {slip.netAmountEuro}
                  </td>
                  <tr className="collapsed">
                    <td colSpan="10">
                    {renderInside(slipsList)}
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>Loading...</div>
  );
};
```

But it doesn't work. I use another two ways of doing this but I want. For every row or the main table I must put the secondary table. Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: is it displaying anything ??

Comment: No it is showing an error about jsx enclosing tag.

Comment: can you show the error ?

Comment: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use this:

In `renderInside` method:

```
{slipsList.map((slip, i) => (  //added this bracket
      <tr key={i}>
         <td>{slip.amount}</td>
      </tr>
    )
 )}
```

In `renderTable` method:

```
{slipsList.map((slip, i) => (   //added this bracket
    <tr key={i}>
      <td className="table-sticky--first-col">
        {slip.confirmationDate}
      </td>
      <td>
        {slip.netAmountEuro}
      </td>
      <tr className="collapsed">
        <td colSpan="10">
          {renderInside(slipsList)}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
  )
)}
```

One more thing, i think you need to pass `slip` inside `{renderInside(slipsList)}` method instead of `slipsList`.

Comment: like this? {renderInside(slipsList, slip)}

Comment: tell me one thing, do you want to pass same `slipsList` array to other function or each value of the array ??

Comment: The values of the two arrays are contained inside slipsList. Therefore with my approach i want to same slipsList to other function. Maybe i'm wrong

Comment: can you show your data `console.log('slipsList', slipsList);` in rendertable method ?

Comment: Array(22)
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object
8
:
Object
9
:
Object
10
:
Object
11
:
Object
12
:
Object
13
:
Object
14
:
Object
15
:
Object
16
:
Object
17
:
Object
18
:
Object
19
:
Object
20
:
Object
21
:
Object